# How do I type ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ and ŝ on a United States International keyboard on on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10 with the United States international keyboard and I can easily type â by pressing ^ (shift+6) followed by pressing a. But when I do ^ followed by c, g, h, j or s, I just get: ^c, ^g, ^h, ^j and ^s respectively.

How do I type these characters on a United States International keyboard on on Windows 10?

**update**: Oh, one more thing... my keyboard doesn't have a numeric keypad.

Comment: Download esperanto keyboard layout [here](https://connectina.co.uk/esperanto/eo-win-keyboard.html) and install it. Then [add keyboard layout](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10)

Comment: You will have to (1) add a language that is expected to have those characters and (2) add a US International keyboard to that language. In most Linux distros you would just need to have the "US International *with dead keys*" layout.

Comment: See http://www.esperanto.org.nz/learn-and-use-esperanto/how-to-type-esperanto-characters/

Comment: @Alex: thanks, I'm aware of alternative layouts, but I'm trying to stay with the US one, which is perfectly doable on Mac, as dead keys work with these characters.

Comment: I think then that @JeffZeitlin answer is a shortest way to use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) for those characters without adding new keyboard layout.

Comment: @Alex It really isn't. And I just tested in Windows (input language: Portuguese / Keyboard: US Int). It produces all the required characters, not only the ones typically used by PT or ES but any other combination, and that without using third-party software or adding Esperanto.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Im the first who advised to use alternative input language, but OP clarified **requirement** - to stay with US keyboard without alternative input language and be able in the same time to use Esperanto characters, that what is question  about and Im pretty sure OP has some reason to use workflow he liked.

Comment: @Alex There's no need to change the input and/or system-wide language either. It just has to be there so we have an icon for toggling keyboard layouts which is this case will be the same layout but added to different languages.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Wait, how would you have "icon for toggling keyboard layouts" without adding extra input layout. Classic Windows 10 installation in US doesn't have any  "icon for toggling keyboard layouts".

Comment: @Alex You can have more than one keyboard layout for the same input language and also the same keyboard layout added to multiple input languages or any combination of those. I have both situations: In one with a US Eng input language I had to add a Spanish keyboard and a notebook from USA where the input languages are ES and PT and to those I added the US Int keyboard (and removed the default ones that won't be used; I might add another if later I decided to use an external keyboard with a different layout.)

Comment: Doesn't the input language change the spelling corrections? If so, changing it to Spanish, would make it useless in English, which is what I write 95% of the time. Am I correct?

Comment: No, changing the input language at the system level doesn't affect the spell-check language, unless the program checks the system language on the way in - with MS Office, it doesn't seem to (it defaults to the system language [EN-US, in my case], not the input language); I'm not sure with any of the OpenFork suites.

Comment: Also note that if you have multiple layouts/input languages configured, Windows seems to maintain the setting separately for each active application.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to include a AHK script that will "emulate" the standard dead-key behavior of the US-International keyboard, and give you the Esperanto characters.

Comment: This script does work at producing the diacritics, but it doesn't "eat" the dead key circunflex, meaning that it will still appear randomly at the the next character typed : 
ĥ^, ĉîam, ŝâtas, etc

Answer (score 3):

These characters are not directly available on the (Windows) US-International keyboard; you would need to paste them from Character Map, use their ALT-codes on the numeric keypad, or use a third-party program such as a macro processor like [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com). Someone has already done a [AHK script to convert 'x' convention to Esperanto characters](https://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/16768). (*see below regarding "'x' convention*)

If you would prefer to configure AutoHotKey to match the behavior of the US-International keyboard, the below AHK script should be saved as Unicode with the Byte-Order mark; it will convert ^ followed by c, g, h, j, and s, or ~ followed by u, as the Esperanto letters.

```
#Hotstring ? C * 

::^c::ĉ
::^C::Ĉ
::^g::ĝ
::^G::Ĝ
::^h::ĥ
::^H::Ĥ
::^j::ĵ
::^J::Ĵ
::^s::ŝ
::^S::Ŝ
::~u::ŭ
::~U::Ŭ
```

Alternatively, use a different keyboard driver that supports the Esperanto characters, though this doesn’t really answer your question, since you specified US-International.

In general, Esperanto text processing is difficult, as there are few if any Esperanto-specific keyboard drivers available; most of the time, one of two alternative conventions are used - the "h" convention, where the altered letters are followed by 'h' (e.g., ĉ is ch, ĝ is gh, ĥ is hh, ĵ is jh, and ŝ is sh), and the 'x' convention, where the altered letters are followed by 'x' (e.g., ĉ is cx, ĝ is gx, ĥ is hx, ĵ is jx, and ŝ is sx). The impression I get is that the 'x' convention is preferred, as 'x' is not otherwise used in Esperanto, and thus straight search-and-replace is adequate to 'fix' the results.

Comment: Please read https://superuser.com/questions/1353165/how-do-i-type-%c4%89-%c4%9d-%c4%a5-%c4%b5-and-%c5%9d-on-a-united-states-international-keyboard-on-on-w#comment2029547_1353165 . Windows automatically activates the "dead keys" feature to pretty much any language other than English. Adding Esperanto for that purpose only and instead of the actual language the OP is intending to use seems surreal. Looking at your name I infer you're native English so I wouldn't expect you being experienced with this things.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - The querent **explicitly** specified the **US-International** keyboard; using another language setting is technically a non-answer to the question. Yes, there are Esperanto keyboard drivers available; had the querent not specified the US-INT layout, I'd have recommended one of them.

Comment: Also, US-Int has dead keys, which is why I'm using it, so I can have the proper layout I want for coding, English and still type all the characters I need for Spanish. On a Mac, dead keys work just fine for these characters, I don't understand why they didn't do the same on Windows.

Comment: It's simply because the developers at MS that did up the US-INT layout failed to have enough imagination to include Eastern European languages and Esperanto in the definition of the layout - US-International really mean "US and Western European", and doesn't include other languages that use the Latin alphabet, like Polish, Romanian, Turkish, Czech, Croatian, _et cetera_.

Comment: I'm aware of that. You need to understand the difference between "(system) language" and "keyboard layout". That's why this is a two-step process as commented. Windows will by default assign the most typical keyboard layout for the language but that doesn't mean you can't add others (and even remove the default one). If I'm installing a Spanish Windows it'll suggest the standard Spanish layout so, if I'm using an US Int then I have to explicitly add that one (and it automatically has the "dead keys" feature). I can then remove the default Spanish keyboard that I won't be using.

Comment: @pupeno You just need to add Spanish as input language, then add the US Int layout to that language. A system tray icon will let you toggle the different layouts.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - I am _quite_ aware of the difference between system language and keyboard layout. I do multilingual document processing, and routinely use the US-International layout - and I've even started building an extended version of it using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, _because_ of the deficiencies in the standard layout. Such creation is _not_ for everyone, however, and my inclinations are (a) to answer the question as asked, unless it's _obviously_ wrong, and (b) to provide answers that are as compatible as possible with what the querent is currently doing.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Spanish, Portuguese, French and other regional languages in Spain, among others, are ALL "Western" and ALL of them need accentuated characters. Mostly vowels but in Spanish you also need the iconic "Ñ".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - Please do not attempt to teach me what I have been doing for at least twenty years. It doesn't matter what other input languages are available in the system; if those languages do not use ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ, or ŝ, any keyboard layout that supports those languages without also supporting Esperanto or another language that includes those characters will not be able to type those characters.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin How condescending of you... Again, this https://superuser.com/questions/1353165/how-do-i-type-%c4%89-%c4%9d-%c4%a5-%c4%b5-and-%c5%9d-on-a-united-states-international-keyboard-on-on-w/1353167?noredirect=1#comment2029568_1353167 and only this, is what the OP needs to do. I know because I'm having the "experience" RIGHT NOW and not with Commodore64 keyboards.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - I most certainly _did_ answer the question as asked - the question specifically asked about the complete set of modified consonants of Esperanto, and specifically about the US-International keyboard in Windows. I am unaware of any other language that uses _all_ of the requested characters; I do know that Spanish uses none of them, and several Eastern European (Slavic) languages use _some_ of them - but not all of them.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - THE QUERENT ISN'T USING LINUX. ***I*** routinely use Windows, and the US-International layout, and I am answering from ***DIRECT*** experience.  Spanish does not use the requested letters, and the US-INT layout, even with Spanish as the system language, does not allow the querent to type the Esperanto characters. Esperanto is not Español, in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: I was doing some work on my extended version of the US-INT keyboard last night, and found a reason why the Esperanto characters weren't included: The MS keyboard layouts are set up to support their legacy 'code page' mechanism, and the US-INT layout supports Windows-1252 (roughly the ISO8859-1 charset). Since the Esperanto chars aren't in 1252/8859-1, they're not in the US-INT layout. Non-MS layouts - like the one I'm building - aren't restricted to code-page compatibility, but programs that use that mechanism may not work with the layout quite as expected.

Comment: I used this script, and while it does work at making the diacritics, it doesn't "eat" the dead key circunflex used, meaning the next character typed will make appear an unasked circunflex, either standalon or as a diacritic : ĥ^, ĉîam, ŝâtas, etc 
And it also deletes the previous character typed.
(on a qwertz keyboard with french input)

Comment: @bookmanB. - I've not noticed any behavior inconsistent with the standard MS keyboard with dead-keys.

Answer (score 1):

Choice for particular approach may depend on how and where  do 
you plan to input those characters. Either way I'd recommend looking into Autohotkey app.

My opinion is that the most efficient approach would be to simply use 
some **transliteration** to type it in, and use auto-conversion later on.

For example, I personally would use such rules for the input text:

```
ĉ   ch  
ĝ   dzh  
ĥ   x   (or kh)   
ĵ   zh  
ŝ   sh  
ŭ   w
```

This is almost kind of 'average translit' (opinions may vary ;)
Although there maybe special convention for this in Esperanto community, 
I would still use the above, because it is more close to widely accepted translit and I don't need to learn 'yet another translit'.

Important is that the substitution should work in both directions, i.e. 
you can automatically convert same text from and to Esperanto spelling.
And thus able to convert the text which already includes mixed spelling.
(But you should check this, as I am not an esperantist myself)

This will allow for making a script, say with Autohotkey, which applies the conversion of the text.

So what you do is simply type the text with Latin characters and then 
you can bind some key to run the script which makes the conversion of 
e.g. currently selected text.

Such approach has benefits:

- typing speed: no need to input special characters
- more familiar (if you already used translit in similar cases)
- in an informal conversation people should understand 
  it even without conversion.